# google endpoints on flex app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-managed-vm

When we use endpoints with std app engine environment
Following lines in app.yaml, defines the starting point of the app

```
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: main.api
```

But as flex engine uses 'gunicorn' to define the staring point as given below

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

How should define `main.py` of my cloud endpoint to be starting point with google app engine in flex environment ?

Edit1:

after the suggestion below from [this link](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstart-app-engine).

I updated my app.yaml to:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:api
service: s2

endpoints_api_service:
  name: echo-api.endpoints.my-project-id.cloud.goog
  config_id: my-config-id
```

but now while deploying, in my [main.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/endpoints/backend/main.py) file I get the import error

```
ImportError: No module named endpoints
```

even changing the import statment to

```
from google.appengine.ext import endpoints
```

does not help

Edit2:

I added the endpoints library to the project lib folder and also added **appengine_config.py** file to take care of this library, still it breaks at `import endpoints`.

for my directory structure refer the image below

[image]

Comment: In general you'd want to go through the standard -> flex migration guide: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/flexible-for-standard-users

Answer (score 1):

A summary from [Quickstart for Endpoints on App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstart-app-engine) (assuming python below, if using other language select the respective examples):

- configure endpoints:

> To configure Endpoints, replace `YOUR-PROJECT-ID` with your own
>   project ID in the `openapi.yaml` configuration file's host field:
>
> ```
> swagger: "2.0"
> info:
>   description: "A simple Google Cloud Endpoints API example."
>   title: "Endpoints Example"
>   version: "1.0.0"
> host: "echo-api.endpoints.YOUR-PROJECT-ID.cloud.goog"
> ```

- deploy your Open API specification:

> To deploy your Open API specification, run the following `gcloud`
>   command:
>
> ```
> gcloud service-management deploy openapi.yaml
> ```
>
> This will create a new Cloud Endpoints service with the name
>   `echo-api.endpoints.YOUR-PROJECT_ID.cloud.goog` if it does not exist,
>   and then update that service's configuration to your Open API
>   specification.
>
> The command returns several lines of information, including a line
>   similar to the following:
>
> ```
> Service Configuration [2016-04-27R2] uploaded for service
> "echo-api.endpoints.[YOUR-PROJECT-ID].cloud.goog"
> ```
>
> Make a note of the service name and the service configuration ID, it
>   is used in the next step.

- update your `app.yaml`:

> Edit `app.yaml` to reflect the Endpoints configuration ID and add the
>   following to enable Endpoints API Management features on App Engine
>   Flex and add the service name and configuration ID:
>
> ```
> beta_settings:
>   use_endpoints_api_management: true
>
> endpoints_api_service:
>   name: echo-api.endpoints.[YOUR-PROJECT-ID].cloud.goog
>   config_id: YOUR-CONFIG-ID # 2016-04-27R2 in this example.
> ```
>
> Save the `app.yaml` file. You will need to repeat these steps and
>   update the `app.yaml` file when you make changes to your Open API
>   specification.

Comment: Hey dan, my main.py file is this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/endpoints/backend/main.py and now when i put "entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:api" in my yaml file, it throws the error on deployment that "ImportError: No module named endpoints". Any help ?

Comment: For flex env dependencies are handled differently. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#dependencies. Maybe also check the example github repo mentioned in that guide.

Comment: hey dan, evening the library uses the same import

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/flexible/endpoints/clients/service_to_service_non_default/appengine_config.py

and mine breaks at that import, I must be missing something more ?

Comment: dependencies, not the import itself

Answer (score 1):

For Endpoints Frameworks v1.0, you have to copy the endpoints module into your app directory to deploy it on Flex. If you're using the Cloud SDK, it's located in `/path/to/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/endpoints-1.0`.

Comment: hey saiyr, can't I add these libraries into "requirement.txt" file ?
what should i exactly add to make sure my import endpoints statement works ?

Comment: No, because v1 (which you're using) isn't on PyPI. I edited my answer. If you use v2 then you would put google-endpoints into your requirements.txt.

Comment: Thank you so much saiyr for you correct guidance. two questions/ 1. as v1-endpoint is not on pip, can I just copy the endpoint folder from sdk to lib folder in my project and add it with appengine_config.py. But this is still giving me same problem. 2. Will using v2 means I will have to change my code of main.py ?

Comment: Regarding 1, yes, that should work. Make sure you're copying the `endpoints` directory, not the `endpoints-1.0` directory. I believe there are also other dependencies you need to add to requirements.txt for Flex, `PyCrypto` being one of them. Regarding 2, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/migrating.

Comment: hey saiyr, pycrpto is added to the requirement.txt. And I have updated the quuestion to shoe the directory structure of the project. Still I am unable to import endpoints in my main.py. Thanks

Comment: Hey saiyr, I got the solution, as the flex environment does not automatically loads the appengine_config.py, so I had to import it in my "main.py" and then making sure all the referred google libraries are in lib, did the job for me

Answer (score 0):

The document/the link you refers to is Extensible Service Proxy provided by Google App Engine which uses OpenAPI specifications which can be invoked using normal http requests. The entry to your endpoint service can be restricted by making use of [Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys-openapi) provided by App Engine. The entire things work only App Engine Flexible Environment.

### OverView GAE endpoints on Flex

Extensible Service Proxy needs to configure differently from our tradition endpoints.

- Deploy the open API configuration using *gcloud service-management deploy openapi.yaml*
- Deploy the API backend. *gcloud service-management configs list --service=[YOUR-PROJECT-ID].appspot.com*
- Replace ENDPOINTS-SERVICE-NAME and ENDPOINTS-CONFIG-ID in app.yaml, then deploy using gcloud app deploy

For App Engine Standard Environment users, a new version of Endpoints(Endpoint Framework 2.0) is available. Currently, endpoint frameworks are not supported in App Engine Flexible Environment. If you want to use your existing code, I suggest using [migration to Endpoint Frameworks 2.0](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/python/migrating).